# retrieve the JSON of nested objects in js

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

I have built a web service using java, and the return value is a parsed object to JSON.

the problem is that I have an object that contains a `Hashmap<>` in it as a parameter, when I parse it to JSON and returns it, How could I handle it in js, how could I get the values of the hashmap.

Here is the object that I parse to JSON.

> Object human;
>
> ```
> Hashmap<String, String> properties;
>
> properties.put("property1", "value");
> properties.put("property2", "value");
> properties.put("property3", "value");
>
> /* here where I got the object that contains several attributes  beside the hashmap that is considered as object*/
>
> human.setProperties(properties);
> ```
>
> return aGson.toJson(human);

Comment: You seem to be confusing Java and JavaScript. They are entirely different. Please review your question and tag it appropriately.

Comment: @rory-mccrossan no no, I built a web service using java, but the return value is JSON and I should handle it with js

Comment: @HasanKhatib We'll need to know how you're passing this to JavaScript.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin I used an ajax request to get the json from this service that I built, now I want to fill the html with this json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've received your JSON text from the web service, parse it in JavaScript as

```
var human = JSON.parse( jsonTextFromWS );
console.log( human.properties.property1 ); // value
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the org.json.JSONObject class, like this:

```
JSONObject jsonHuman = new JSONObject( human );
```

It should use reflection to find all the public fields and build a valid JSON object for you.

http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html